# How to draw a spark diagram in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following digram. I dont know how start. Any suggestion about a library of anything to do that will be so appreciated[image]

Comment: Im not yet started bcz i dont know from where I should to start. I will get a look to your provided library name

Comment: No, I'm mistaken, drawing borders in `matrix` is very complicated. You only have to nest a `tabular` inside normal Ti*k*Z node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a starting point

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}]
\node (1) at (0,0) {%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    This & is\\\hline
    a & table\\\hline
    inside & a node\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\node (2) at (4,-1.5) {%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    This & is\\\hline
    another & table\\\hline
    inside & a node\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\node (3) at (0,-3) {%
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
    This & is\\\hline
    the third & table\\\hline
    inside & a node\\\hline
\end{tabular}};
\end{scope}
\draw[blue,very thick,latex-] (2) edge (1.south) edge (3.north);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\bfseries}]
\path (1.north) node[above] {Title 1}
    (2.north) node[above] {Title 2}
    (3.north west) node[above right] {Title 3};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now I think you can draw your diagram yourself.